# inline-block overflowing outside container

Tags: css, containers

I have a container that I don't want to set as inline-block and that contains inline-block elements.
These elements will overflow out of the container instead of extending it.
How can I manage to prevent this behaviour ?

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZaPY)

```
#inline-block-container {
background-color: red;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.inline-block-element {
background-color: blue;
width: 50px;
height: 30px;
margin: 10px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

In this demo, I would like the red rectangle to expand (even out of viewport) to contain (visually) all the blue rectangles.

-Edit-

On my real page :
[image: Display]

You can see the background (gradient light gray) stopping at the right border of the window (before scrolling to the right).
There is also a bootstrap tooltip (in black) that is wrongly positionned and same for a context menu.
The container, the body and the html tag won't extand outside of the initial view because the inline-block elements overflow outside of their container.

I can't set the size in css because the content of the elements (dimgray) can change.

I tried to set the container as display:table : same result.
I tried position:absolute : it brakes things and doesn't solve the issue.
I tried inline-flex : same result.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you use `display: table` instead

Comment: Or...`position:absolute` ?

Comment: So you don't want the blue rectangles to move to the next line if they can't fit on one line depending on screen size?

Comment: `display: inline-flex` should also work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Positioning the parent div absolutely will enable this but this may not be suitable for your requirements.

```
#inline-block-container {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
```

```css
#inline-block-container {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
.inline-block-element {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="inline-block-container">
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
</div>
```

Or as mentioned by Nenad Vracar...`display:table`

```
#inline-block-container {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
  width: auto;
}
```

```css
#inline-block-container {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
  width: auto;
}
.inline-block-element {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="inline-block-container">
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
</div>
```

Or as also mentioned by Nenad Vracar...`display:inline-flex`

```
#inline-block-container {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
}
```

```css
#inline-block-container {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
}
.inline-block-element {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="inline-block-container">
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
  <div class="inline-block-element"></div>
</div>
```

Essentially, these methods are virtually [**indistinguishable**](https://jsfiddle.net/sue8hyxL/1/) from using `display:inline-block` and it's "shrink to fit" properties. The line boxes and `white-space:nowrap` work in basically the same way to maintain the background color.

Knowing why you are averse to `inline-block` would go a long way to identifying the most suitable alternative.

Comment: The solutions worked for the demo so I marked the answer as a solution even though it didn't solve my issue. I think my issue may not be related to inline-block after all. I changed my page so it would not go outside viewport to prevent the bug for tooltip and context menu as a temporary solution. Thank you for your time.