# inline-block overflow the body section

Tags: html, css, input, containers, display

My question is similar to this post, except I still having trouble to display the input text as inline-block --> 
[inline-block overflowing outside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042024/inline-block-overflowing-outside-container)

I want have 5 input texts and I want to wrap them like:

"Item 1"

"Item 2" "Item 3"

"Item 4" "Item 5"

My HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <div id="inputs">
        <label> Email </label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100">
        </div>
        <label> Address </label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address" maxlength="50">
        </div>
             .....
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#inputs { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    label {
      ....
    }

    div {
     width: 100%;
       ....
    }
}
```

I also tried display: table, position: absolute and display: inline-flex. But they are not meeting my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```css
#inputs .frmField{ 
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#inputs .frmField:nth-child(2), #inputs .frmField:nth-child(4){
  clear: both
}
label {
  display: block;
}
div {
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <div id="inputs">
        <div class="frmField">
         <label> Email 1</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100">
        </div>
        <div class="frmField">
         <label> Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="frmField">
         <label> Address 3</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="frmField">
         <label> Address 4</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="frmField">
         <label> Address 5</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address" maxlength="50">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using table for creating form

**SNIPPET**

```html
<h1>A FORM</h1>
<table class="form">
    <tbody id="inputs">
        <tr>
            <td><label> Email </label><td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> Address </label><td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> Address </label><td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> Address </label><td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> Address </label><td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```